# Add a color legend for a datatable with colored background in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a datatable in shiny. The table background is colored. Now, I want to add a color legend below the table, if possible, with the breaks added as labels. Any suggestions.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
      DT::dataTableOutput("distPlot")
     )


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- DT::renderDataTable({
      brks <- quantile(df, probs = seq(.05, .95, .1), na.rm = TRUE)
      clrs = brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "RdYlGn")
      datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```